# How to render a nested route from router link inside component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

this is a bit of an architecture question. I am fairly new to working with Vue and don't completely understand a good structure and architecture I need to use. I am using in within a Laravel application, if that helps.

I have a main file, index.php, where I have a Vue router instance. This has the following structure

```
<div>
<router-link to="/home"></router-link>
<router-link to="/about"></router-link>
<router-link to="/projects"></router-link>
<router-link to="/contact"></router-link>
</div>

<router-view></router-view>
```

This works fine and well. But, I want to extend the functionality. Each of these routes renders a corresponding component (ie HomeComponent, AboutComponent, etc). Within one component in particular (ProjectComponent) I want to have nested routes.

This is the nested route in question in my `routes.js` file:

```
{
    path: '/projects',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/:project',
            component: ProjectShowComponent,
        }
    ]
},
```

So, when you click on the `projects` route and get to the `ProjectComponent`, you are presented with various projects that have their own `router-link` to that particular project. I thought because the `ProjectComponent` was an extension of the root Vue instance, that the `router-link`'s within the file would still render the new component in the `router-view`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Am I totally off base with how I should architect something like this, or is there something in the routing that is off? Any help or thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vue-router to do this then you'll have to have a look at passing props to the child component, here is the guide from vue router https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Another option would be to let laravel handle the routing of the application.